# Ubuntu 20.04 and amdgpu-pro-21.10-1247438 can't start X

Tags: amdgpu

I tried to install amdgpu-pro-21.10-1247438-ubuntu-20.04 driver to be able to get hardware aceleration on my machine but after installing without errors and rebooting I have no login screen.

When I login trough console and try to startx there is an error and it exits.

Bellow are excerpts of Xorg.0.log file, if you need more info just ask.

```
    [   220.407] X.Org X Server 1.20.9
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   220.407] Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-140-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   220.407] Current Operating System: Linux Valium 5.4.0-72-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 17:35:00 UTC 2021 x86_64
[   220.407] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   220.407] Build Date: 08 April 2021  12:29:22PM
[   220.407] xorg-server 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   220.408] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
...
[   220.516] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   220.516] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   220.516] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   220.517] (II) [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[   220.517] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   220.517] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   220.517] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   220.517] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   220.517] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   220.518] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   220.518] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   220.518]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 0.0.2
[   220.518]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   220.518] (**) FBDEV(2): claimed PCI slot 4@0:0:0
[   220.518] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[   220.518] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   220.518] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[   220.518] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   220.518] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   220.519] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
...
```

Comment: amdgpu, already installed, provides hardware acceleration. And if you install the proprietary overlay (again, for no good reason) then you must disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Do you mean if I install the normal one instead of the pro version?

Comment: The "normal one" is installed automatically whenever the installer detects compatible hardware (new AMD cards) or install *radeon* for old AMD cards.

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto I don't think I have secure boot active.
`sudo mokutil --sb-state​
EFI variables are not supported on this system
`
Can you tell me step by step, or link, what I need to do to?

Comment: Secure Boot is applicable only to UEFI and UEFI mode. BIOS or UEFI in Legacy mode don't have Secure Boot. Now, if it's UEFI then it Ubuntu should have been installed in UEFI mode but the mokutil result seems to suggest a legacy installation.

Comment: So, that is not the problema why my X won't start with the AMD drivers. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Installing in legacy mode in any modern hardware can have all sorts of problems, namely hardware initialization. You should have just installed in the proper UEFI mode and do not mess with graphics drivers that are installed by default and just work, for AMD or Intel cards. That's all.